# pynput installation failing in python 2.7

Tags: python, pip

I tried to install pynput by doing `pip install pynput`.
It throws an error in pyobjc-core-2.5.1. It tries to uninstall and install the package but an exception is thrown.

```
pip install pynput
Collecting pynput
  Using cached pynput-1.3.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: six in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from pynput)
Requirement already satisfied: enum34; python_version == "2.7" in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from pynput)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-Quartz>=3.0; sys_platform == "darwin" (from pynput)
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_Quartz-3.2.1-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.whl
Collecting pyobjc-core>=3.2.1 (from pyobjc-framework-Quartz>=3.0; sys_platform == "darwin"->pynput)
  Using cached pyobjc_core-3.2.1-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.whl
Collecting pyobjc-framework-Cocoa>=3.2.1 (from pyobjc-framework-Quartz>=3.0; sys_platform == "darwin"->pynput)
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_Cocoa-3.2.1-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.whl
Installing collected packages: pyobjc-core, pyobjc-framework-Cocoa, pyobjc-framework-Quartz, pynput
  Found existing installation: pyobjc-core 2.5.1
    Uninstalling pyobjc-core-2.5.1:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 778, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 299, in move
    copytree(src, real_dst, symlinks=True)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 208, in copytree
    raise Error, errors
Error: [('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/__init__.py', '/var/folders/hd/p6kgn6zx2q98dhht353zy1ph0000gn/T/pip-sP_xhJ-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/__init__.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/hd/p6kgn6zx2q98dhht353zy1ph0000gn/T/pip-sP_xhJ-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/__init__.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/__init__.pyc', '/var/folders/hd/p6kgn6zx2q98dhht353zy1ph0000gn/T/pip-sP_xhJ-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/__init__.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/hd/p6kgn6zx2q98dhht353zy1ph0000gn/T/pip-sP_xhJ-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/__init__.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/AppCategories.py', '/var/folders/hd/p6kgn6zx2q98dhht353zy1ph0000gn/T/pip-sP_xhJ-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/AppCategories.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/hd/p6kgn6zx2q98dhht353zy1ph0000gn/T/pip-sP_xhJ-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/AppCategories.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/AppCategories.pyc', '/var/folders/hd/p6kgn6zx2q98dhht353zy1ph0000gn/T/pip-sP_xhJ-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/AppCategories.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/hd/p6kgn6zx2q98dhht353zy1ph0000gn/T/pip-sP_xhJ-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/AppCategories.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/AppHelper.py', '/var/folders/hd/p6kgn6zx2q98dhht353zy1ph0000gn/T/pip-sP_xhJ-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/AppHelper.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/hd/p6kgn6zx2q98dhht353zy1ph0000gn/T/pip-sP_xhJ-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/AppHelper.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/AppHelper.pyc', '/var/folders/hd/p6kgn6zx2q98dhht353zy1ph0000gn/T/pip-sP_xhJ-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/AppHelper.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/hd/p6kgn6zx2q98dhht353zy1ph0000gn/T/pip-sP_xhJ-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/AppHelper.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/Conversion.py', '/var/folders/hd/p6kgn6zx2q98dhht353zy1ph0000gn/T/pip-sP_xhJ-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/Conversion.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/hd/p6kgn6zx2q98dhht353zy1ph0000gn/T/pip-sP_xhJ-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/Conversion.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/Conversion.pyc', '/var/folders/hd/p6kgn6zx2q98dhht353zy1ph0000gn/T/pip-sP_xhJ-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/Conversion.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/hd/p6kgn6zx2q98dhht353zy1ph0000gn/T/pip-sP_xhJ-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/Conversion.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/Debugging.py', '/var/folders/hd/p6kgn6zx2q98dhht353zy1ph0000gn/T/pip-sP_xhJ-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/Debugging.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/hd/p6kgn6zx2q98dhht353zy1ph0000gn/T/pip-sP_xhJ-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/Debugging.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/Debugging.pyc', '/var/folders/hd/p6kgn6zx2q98dhht353zy1ph0000gn/T/pip-sP_xhJ-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/Debugging.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/hd/p6kgn6zx2q98dhht353zy1ph0000gn/T/pip-sP_xhJ-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/Debugging.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/FndCategories.py', '/var/folders/hd/p6kgn6zx2q98dhht353zy1ph0000gn/T/pip-sP_xhJ-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/FndCategories.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/hd/p6kgn6zx2q98dhht353zy1ph0000gn/T/pip-sP_xhJ-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/FndCategories.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/FndCategories.pyc', '/var/folders/hd/p6kgn6zx2q98dhht353zy1ph0000gn/T/pip-sP_xhJ-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/FndCategories.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/hd/p6kgn6zx2q98dhht353zy1ph0000gn/T/pip-sP_xhJ-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/FndCategories.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/KeyValueCoding.py', '/var/folders/hd/p6kgn6zx2q98dhht353zy1ph0000gn/T/pip-sP_xhJ-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/KeyValueCoding.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/hd/p6kgn6zx2q98dhht353zy1ph0000gn/T/pip-sP_xhJ-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/KeyValueCoding.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/KeyValueCoding.pyc', '/var/folders/hd/p6kgn6zx2q98dhht353zy1ph0000gn/T/pip-sP_xhJ-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/KeyValueCoding.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/hd/p6kgn6zx2q98dhht353zy1ph0000gn/T/pip-sP_xhJ-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/KeyValueCoding.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/MachSignals.py', '/var/folders/hd/p6kgn6zx2q98dhht353zy1ph0000gn/T/pip-sP_xhJ-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/MachSignals.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/hd/p6kgn6zx2q98dhht353zy1ph0000gn/T/pip-sP_xhJ-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/MachSignals.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/MachSignals.pyc', '/var/folders/hd/p6kgn6zx2q98dhht353zy1ph0000gn/T/pip-sP_xhJ-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/MachSignals.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/hd/p6kgn6zx2q98dhht353zy1ph0000gn/T/pip-sP_xhJ-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/MachSignals.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/NibClassBuilder.py', '/var/folders/hd/p6kgn6zx2q98dhht353zy1ph0000gn/T/pip-sP_xhJ-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/NibClassBuilder.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/hd/p6kgn6zx2q98dhht353zy1ph0000gn/T/pip-sP_xhJ-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/NibClassBuilder.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/NibClassBuilder.pyc', '/var/folders/hd/p6kgn6zx2q98dhht353zy1ph0000gn/T/pip-sP_xhJ-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/NibClassBuilder.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/hd/p6kgn6zx2q98dhht353zy1ph0000gn/T/pip-sP_xhJ-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/NibClassBuilder.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/Signals.py', '/var/folders/hd/p6kgn6zx2q98dhht353zy1ph0000gn/T/pip-sP_xhJ-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/Signals.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/hd/p6kgn6zx2q98dhht353zy1ph0000gn/T/pip-sP_xhJ-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/Signals.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/Signals.pyc', '/var/folders/hd/p6kgn6zx2q98dhht353zy1ph0000gn/T/pip-sP_xhJ-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/Signals.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/hd/p6kgn6zx2q98dhht353zy1ph0000gn/T/pip-sP_xhJ-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/Signals.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/TestSupport.py', '/var/folders/hd/p6kgn6zx2q98dhht353zy1ph0000gn/T/pip-sP_xhJ-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/TestSupport.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/hd/p6kgn6zx2q98dhht353zy1ph0000gn/T/pip-sP_xhJ-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/TestSupport.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/TestSupport.pyc', '/var/folders/hd/p6kgn6zx2q98dhht353zy1ph0000gn/T/pip-sP_xhJ-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/TestSupport.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/hd/p6kgn6zx2q98dhht353zy1ph0000gn/T/pip-sP_xhJ-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/TestSupport.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools', '/var/folders/hd/p6kgn6zx2q98dhht353zy1ph0000gn/T/pip-sP_xhJ-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/hd/p6kgn6zx2q98dhht353zy1ph0000gn/T/pip-sP_xhJ-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools'")]
```

Comment: You don't have permission to write to the output directory. Try a virtualenv.

Comment: I have the same problem under OSX, even with sudo. Did you have a solution for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am using macOS Sierra Version 10.12.6, and from what I have heard, this is a common issue following the release of OS X El Capitan, at least on Mac platforms.

What happens is basically you have triggered something called the [System Integrity Protection](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899) built in the OS itself, which prevents some paths of root filesystems from being modified - even by the root user. So, using `sudo` would not work either.

Using pip, you may include the flag `--user` in your command and install files onto your home directory to tackle this issue. So, try executing the command `pip install pynput --user`.

For further info, consider checking this [article](http://marcelog.github.io/articles/mac_osx_python_pip_install_operation_not_permitted.html).